# Find contours of objects on photo

Tags: java, android

I need to find contours of objects on images and that borders paint in blue ( like parameter I have Bitmap). Is there any library for this task or can anyone suggest me concrete algorithm for this task ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) is a widely-used library for image recognition tasks. It is not written in Java itself, but it does have bindings for Java and it can definitely be used on Android.