# insert the outline of a person while taking a photo

Tags: android, android-camera

I am not sure if it is possible to make. I need to put a outline of a person while taking a photo to ensure that the user take the photo in the correct position and correct size before starting using it for other stuffs. Is it possible to develop? I try to look in the **Android camera class** but there was nothing for that or at least I could not find it.

Answer (score 0):

This task requires image processing of the image that you are going to capture but before this   you have to get the image real time for this try using this [code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485141/using-android-view-surfaceview-with-a-camera-on-part-of-the-screen) help using `surfaceView` and now for the simplication of image processing task you have to capture the photo with some signle color background like Blue or what ever just different from the person's clothing color

Now at this stage you can process the image very easily by just using the [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9870931/find-contours-of-objects-on-photo) here for this